# MySQL on Windows - CRLF vs LF - Some Issues

Tags: mysql, windows, newline

I am trying to insert into a MySQL database - and I have various text fields that are multi-line.  In my SQL I am replacing all CRLF (\R\L) with LF (\L).  My issue here is two fold.

The First issue is that it seems that while I know that my stripping routine works (I have checked to make sure that the CRLF has been changed to LF only) - when it gets into the database - it seems to have CRLF back at the end of each line..

The second issue is that this database will be moved from a windows server to a linux server - where the CRLF at the end is introducing an extra space between each line.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent MySQL on Windows from adding in those CR back to the strings I am trying to insert?

Bradley

Comment: A linefeed is `\n`, not `\L`.

Comment: *when it gets into the database - it seems to have CRLF back at the end of each line..* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3b0a1d147d4ed2edf62fad4afc66cd9

Comment: Akina - yes - I can updated it once I have the data in the Linux server.   But I am trying to figure out if this is a normal issue with MySQL and Windows - or am I doing something wrong ?   Missing some setting somewhere?